# Return column headers rather than TRUE or FALSE value in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with column and row headers and the relationship between the Column and Row headers indicated by True or False.

|   |Green  |Yellow |Red|
| --- | ---- |---- |---- |
|Bananas    |TRUE   |TRUE   |TRUE|
|Orange |TRUE   |TRUE   |FALSE|
|Tangelo    |TRUE   |TRUE   |TRUE|
|Apple  |TRUE   |TRUE   |TRUE|
|Grapefruit |FALSE  |TRUE   |FALSE|
|Rambutan   |FALSE  |FALSE  |TRUE|
I'm trying to derive a formula in Google Sheets that can search for TRUE and either return both (for example)
|Column1|Column2|
|---|---|
|Bananas|Green|
|Bananas|Yellow|
|Bananas|Red|
|Orange|Green|
etc
OR alternatively just a formula that would return
|Column1|
|---|
|Bananas|
|Bananas|
|Bananas|
|Orange|
etc

whenever TRUE appears.

I've tried a variety of Index Match, VLookup and Hlookup formulas but I can't quite wrap my head around how to structure this problem.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Example Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YDo_Z-wbO5D3m-y7ZPXb0OGfK83ODe15rYUzACxoitI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You want to return true or false or the name of the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D=TRUE, A2:A&"×"&B1:D1, )), "×"),
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D, A2:A&"_"&B1:D1,)),"where Col1 <>''"), "_"))
```

and see if that helps?